# Combine text and add blank line before each file

Tags: text-processing, files

I want to combine multiple text files in a directory to a new file while leaving new lines between files.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, it could be as easy as:

some globbing to grab your files (filea, fileb, filec, etc.)

```
FILES=`ls file*`
```

then concatenate them

```
for i in $FILES; do cat "${i}" >> newfile; echo "" >> newfile; done
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with `GNU find`:

```
td=$(mktemp -d);printf '\n\n' > "$td/2"
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cat {} "$td/2" \; | head -n -2 > "$td/log"
```

`find` gets the regular files in the current directory and passes them to `cat` which also has the empty lines file concatenated.Finally the output is given to `head` which deletes the trailing empty lines and then stored in the log file.

```
perl -lpe '$\ = eof && !eof() ? "\n\n" : $/' *.files
```